# SAS specific observation format

Tags: variables, format, sas

I would like to create a new variable in SAS which takes the value 1 if an observation in the variable "TEXT" contains 8 numbers. The problem is, that TEXT is a character variable. Is it possible to make some kind of a format search in SAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by '8 numbers' you actually mean 8 digits. For 8 separate numbers, that would be different.
So something like the code below might help.
The modifier 'kd' meaning KEEP DIGITS in COMPRESS function does the magic here:

```
data indata;
length TEXT $20;
input TEXT;
datalines;
a
123
12345678
A12345678
;
run;

data outdata;
set indata;
length TEXT_DIGITS $20 _8_DIGIT_INDICATOR 3;
TEXT_DIGITS = compress(TEXT, , 'kd');
if length(TEXT_DIGITS)=8 then _8_DIGIT_INDICATOR = 1;
run;
```

Adjust the logic as you need - e.g. if no other character in input value is allowed or something else.
Also functions like ANYDIGIT, NOTDIGIT might be useful.

Comment: That really helped. I meant digits, yes.  If I don't want to have the observations where the digits are separated by for instance letters, "." or "/", is there an easy way to remove these?

Comment: Also, in this code the procedure is only done on one dataset, indata. Is it possible to get sas to do it for a lot of datasets, say a hundred, all contained in one library?